# how to add drag n drop functionality on module's grid list in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add Drag n Drop functionality to custom module grid list(admin panel). So i can manage sort order like if i want to show post on frontend by changing sort order via drag-n-drop grid list. Please anybody can tell me how can i?

Comment: any body have any idea about it,  Please help me thank you.

Comment: Guys,  i solve it.

Comment: How did you solve that? I'm looking for a drag and drop functionality for my custom module in Magento 1.9 backend and I wonder if you could share your solution? Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137661)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137661)